# skip/bypass data on A mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on some charts and I need to find out how I can make my query skip x records on a select.

Lets say, I have 100 Records in my MySQL database.
and I want to select, but buypass 9, or skip 9 (whatever we should call it)..
 so I'm selecting:
 id 1
 id 10
 id 19 etc etc..
How am I able to do so in a query ?

I have tried to get the values in a for loop
by incrementing `$i` with $offset (how many I want to bypass)
and then use the `$data[$i]['value'];`
but is was not able to get that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
Select * from foo where id%9=1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from `users` where MOD(`id`,9) = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

The Mysql LIMIT command allows you to skip (10) records, and return (50) records

```
SELECT *
FROM FOO
LIMIT 10, 50
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.  This will return records 10 through 60.

Comment: @Sable Foste I was creating an example where I used (50) in my description. Sorry for the confusion.